# How to remove firmware warning

Tags: prusa-i3, slic3r, firmware

I'm operating my Prusa i3 MK3 through Octoprint. Basically, this means I can start prints from remote. However, there's the firmware version warning which requires me to press the knob and confirm that message.

I now found a line of G-Code in Printer Settings / Custom G-code which is probably doing this:

```
M115 U3.6.0 ; tell printer latest fw version
```

I'm not very familiar with G-Code yet, so before I remove that line, I wanted to know whether that's all I need to do or if there's something else to consider.

Answer (score 5):

Removing that line will not affect your printer, except that it will get rid of the warning displayed on the screen.

> I wanted to know [...] if there's something else to consider.

You should probably upgrade your firmware to the latest version to benefit from a couple of bugfixes and performance increases.

Comment: I had a couple issues with the last firmware upgrade. Therefore I want to keep this version as long as the printer works fine for me.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Maybe these issues can be solved with [Ask Question](/questions/ask)? ;)

Comment: @0scar: unfortunately that's unlikely for my case. I first used the Prusa forum. Then I had two phone calls over several hours with Prusa support without any result. I then returned the printer in warranty. They sent me a printer back which looked like a complete rebuild.